# In Sharepoint KQL: How to query against List property with space in the name?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to query against a SharePoint List using KQL including some properties of that list that have a space in their names.
Example:

```
Src State:"WA" Prod Id:"X12" SomeFreeText PATH:http://server/sites/items/New%20Items/*
```

The free-text filter works as expected when alone, but returns nothing when including those property filters, such as "Src State".

I assume that is a problem with the space in the name. So, I've tried changing the space to "%20" and to "*x0020*" and even enclosing the property name between quotes (single and double), but not results found!

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a KQL search on list it's a little bit more complex than just using the column name. KQL is a part of Search Service and the columns have to become managed properties. Managed property names cannot contain spaces. SharePoint automatically creates managed properties from site columns, but if the column is directly added to list (and not as a site column), then you have to create managed property manually in Search Administration.

So if the columns are site columns, then there is a specific naming convention on how the managed property names are created (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx). If "Src State" and "Prod Id" columns are simple (say Text, or Choice), then the following query should work:

```
SrcStateOWSTEXT:"WA" ProdIdOWSTEXT:"X12" SomeFreeText PATH:http://server/sites/items/New%20Items/*
```

If this doesn't work - please check the Search Schema in Search Administration whether the managed properties for these columns have been created. If not, then you will have to create them manually and ReIndex/ReCrawl list content. Instructions on how to do that are here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx

Comment: Finally we decided to take other approach: First get docs. filtered by free-text with KQL, then get all the doc's properties with CAML and then filter by property. Which is still less than optimal, but faster to implement than your right-way-to-do solution. Next time, we'll start making site properties. Thanks!